# Problem with temporary unnamed pipe in bash script

Tags: bash, pipe

I have the following question:

When I execute the following script directly in a terminal window, the commands behave as expected.

```
$ diff <(echo tmp) <(echo tmp1)
1c1
< tmp
---
> tmp1
```

However when I write the same command in a shell script

```
#! /bin/bash
diff <(echo tmp) <(echo tmp1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
$ sh test.sh
test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 2: ` diff <(echo tmp) <(echo tmp1)'
```

Initially I thought this was an issue with diff, but this also happens with other commands. Does anybody have an idea what causes the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
bash test.sh
```

or

```
chmod ugo+x test.sh
./test.sh
```

Works fine for me when I do either.

Looks like the syntax is not supported by the bourne shell (sh).

Comment: Thanks, did not think of the differences between bash and bourne. This solved the problem!

Comment: @sugo: If your problem is solved, do consider accepting codaddict's answer.  There's a tick outline under the answer's score you click on to do that.

Answer (score 1):

When bash is invoked using `sh`, it starts up in a special, POSIX-compliant mode.  This has different syntax, which I guess explains the different results.

See [bashref of POSIX mode](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/BashPOSIXMode.html), #22: "process substitution is not available".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I though that #! /bin/bash at the beginning of the script would be sufficient.

Comment: @sugo: The shebang is overridden when you specify the interpreter. It isn't necessarily running Bash in POSIX mode unless `sh` is symlinked to `bash`. So it's actually using whatever `sh` represents on your system. One way to see this is to create a file consisting of `ls -l /proc/$$/exe` called "showshell" and run it with `sh ./showshell` and `bash ./showshell`, and you'll see the symlink. On my system, `sh` is `/bin/dash`.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax doesn't look familiar. Are you sure you are using bash in your terminal? You can verify by typing `echo $SHELL`.

Comment: I have this working as per qn on a bash on osx, and failing for a bash on debian, both version 2.05b.0(1)-release.